# Cpp Compile "error: unknown type name" when initializing object as member variable of other class

Tags: c++, class, c++17, member-variables

I'm new to C++. I am initializing a class object `Node` in another class `LCache`. When I try to compile my code, I get the following error:

```
Line 22: Char 5: error: unknown type name 'left'
    left -> next = right;
    ^
```

Below is the code I have written:

```
class Node{
public:
    int k;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    
    Node (int key){
        k=key;
        prev=NULL;
        next=NULL;
    }
};

class LCache {
private:
    Node* left = new Node(0);
    Node* right = new Node(0);
    left -> next = right;
    right -> prev = left;
...
```

When I move `left -> next = right;` and `right -> prev = left;` inside a method in `class LCache`, the error goes away. Can you explain the reason here?

Comment: You need to put code like that inside functions. Look at the `Node` constructor versus where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform non-declaration statements inside of a class declaration, like you are trying to do.  You need to perform them inside of a class member function instead, or in this case inside of the class constructor (like you did with `Node`), eg:

```
class Node{
public:
    int k;
    Node* prev;
    Node* next;
    
    Node (int key){
        k = key;
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

class LCache {
private:
    Node* left = new Node(0);
    Node* right = new Node(0);

    LCache() {
        left->next = right;
        right->prev = left;
    }

    ~LCache() {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }

    ...
};
```

---

That being said:

`NULL` is deprecated in modern C++, use `nullptr` instead.

And you should use smart pointers whenever you have owned pointers that need freeing when they are done being used.  Or better, just don't use objects dynamically when you don't actually need to.

Try something more like this instead:

```
class Node{
public:
    int k;
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* next = nullptr;
    
    Node (int key) : k(key) {}
};

class LCache {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node> left = std::make_unique<Node>(0);
    std::unique_ptr<Node> right = std::make_unique<Node>(0);

    LCache() {
        left->next = right;
        right->prev = left;
    }

    ...
};

/* alternatively:

class LCache {
private:
    Node left{0};
    Node right{0};

    LCache() {
        left.next = &right;
        right.prev = &left;
    }

    ...
};
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to do an assignment in the declaration of the class type. That makes no sense!

You probably wanted to write things such as "assign to `left`'s `next` field the value…" in some *method* of your code.

This far, this is plain invalid C++ – maybe go a little slower in your C++ intro. The step from "I write a C++ class and assign values to its fields" to "I build a graph" is non-negligible.